# Prevent from Intellij Idea inspection show controller methods as Unused

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, code-inspection

I have Spring MVC project (gradle, kotlin) and Idea inspection shows me my MVC controller methods as unused.
How can I make the inspection tool recognize that those methods are entry points and should not be analyzed for usages?

Comment: Some code examples would be helpful. Do workarounds from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24759 help?

Comment: So it requires to use Spring MVC plugin? Hm ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mark the spring mvc annotations such as `@PostMapping`, `@GetMapping` etc as entrypoint annotations in the idea inspection profile
[image: screenshot]